# Can FileMaker Server 13 import records from a table within the same file?

Tags: filemaker

I have a script that works correctly on a server machine when running within FileMaker Pro 13, but raises errors when run within FileMaker Server 13. Both are running under Windows. The portion that is raising the error is an `Import Record` script step that imports from one table within a file into another table within the same file.

The error returned is 100, "File is missing," so I'm wondering if this is something not supported when running a script within FileMaker Server. If that's the case, I'm thinking that perhaps exporting the records to a temporary file and importing from that might be a workaround, but before I start down that road, I want to check and see if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: no, Server Side Scripts can't import from a FileMaker file. From FM's help site: http://help.filemaker.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/7035/~/import%2Fexport-script-on-filemaker-server

> Importing/exporting directly to and from another FileMaker Pro file is not supported via a FileMaker Server scheduled script.

Yes, exporting to an .xlsx, .csv or .txt file in the temporary directory is a common work-around. I use it frequently. If you want to avoid a temporary file, you can also grab all of the indices to a variable and loop through them, creating records. [HyperLists](http://www.modularfilemaker.org/module/hyperlist/) come in handy for this.